# Что подразумевает фраза: "Приостановить работу и перевести в тестовый режим"?

Tags: смысл

Дайте, пожалуйста, разъяснение, что подразумевает фраза: Приостановить работу и перевести в тестовый режим"?

Comment: «Тестовый режим» — это разработанная функция для ОС Windows, которая позволяет переключить работу вашей системы с общедоступного (стандартного) режима на «специальный». Особенностью такого режима является то, что при его активации блокируются некоторые инструменты безопасности, а именно отключается так называемая «проверка цифровых подписей» для драйверов...

Comment: https://winda10.com/optimizatsiya/kak-otklyuchit-testovyiy-rezhim-windows-10.html

Comment: Вопрос не про Виндоус

Comment: Может ли эта формулировка означать полное отключение?

Comment: не ясно откуда фраза и о чём конкретно речь, но по логике, тестовый режим нужен для поиска ошибок или сбоев в работе программы, или для действия в обход ряда алгоритмов программы в её рабочем режиме. То есть активность будет, но не равная рабочему режиму программы.